# Is it safe to mix vegetable and animal fats?

Tags: oil, fat, cooking-myth

There are so many russian internet-resourses that - without any proof - warn about mixing the above, because it can "drastically increase the fat absorption", but I couldn't find the same claim in english internet.

So now I am confused, if it is *safe* or *not* and, more important, *why*.

Comment: "increase fat absorption" where? Notice that we don't discuss nutrition issues on this site. So, if they are saying that your body digests mixed fat in a different way than pure fat, your question is offtopic. If they are saying that e.g. a blini fried in a mix will absorb more fat than in fat of pure origin, this can be answered here, but it has nothing to do with food safety. A blin which has absorbed fat is just as safe as one which hasn't.

Comment: @rumtscho the first case, of course:.

Comment: I understand that you want to have an answer. But the story of your question illustrates that the nutrition knowledge of random people on the Internet is not to be trusted. Our site's content is entirely made up from the opinions of random people. So we decided, at the beginning of our site, that we will **not** discuss questions on "is X healthy", not because they are not interesting, but because the information we can provide is worse than useless. So sorry, but I have to close your question. A list of what is on topic: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Safety, from the perspective of this site, is short term.  Will you get acutely ill if you eat something, within about 2 days?

From this perspective, there is absolutely no safety issue with mixing fats of vegetable and animal origin.  Frying a steak in vegetable oil, or sauteeing vegetables in bacon fat is perfectly *safe*.